# Find if a site has been renamed via change collection

Tags: changelog

I'm trying to write a script to find ot if a site has changed title. This is what I have so far:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://dev/teams/Kittens

$changeQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeQuery $false,$false
$changeQuery.Web = $true
$changeQuery.Update= $true

$changeCollection = $site.GetChanges($changeQuery)
```

With this query I can get the change that shows the update, which is what happens when a site title is changed. However, all kinds of updates are returned and I can't find any way to see if it is specifically a title change that has happened. Does anyone know if it is possible to find only updates that are site title changes?

[updated] changed from Rename-property to Update, since this whas the one that was triggered

Comment: Filtering by Object Type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408061(v=office.14).aspx
Filtering by Change Type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408067(v=office.14).aspx

There are a couple components you are missing. Unless you are using a strictly controlled environment it is very posible that using the above query you would never see the site name change you are looking for. Check out how to page through the change log and try using the change filter from the above articles. Unfortunately I do not have time to to a proof of concept, but this should get you started.

Comment: Why would i not see the update? I realize that if a lot of updates happen, then I could miss it, but a loop that fethces the rest of the changes should fix that. I am already filtering by Object type (web) and change type (update), so I'm not sure what you mean!

Comment: I was referring to the query limit on GetChanges. You have to page through using the tokens. The update should be there.

Comment: Yes, the update is there, but all kind of updates are returned, and I'm looking for a way to find only the updates that are title change. I need a way to find what kind of update that has happened. I don't want all of them!

Answer (score 3):

how about?

```
## SharePoint Reference [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration") [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration") [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server.Search") [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server") 


function global:Get-ChangeLog($url, $minutes, $changetype)
{
 trap [Exception] {
  write-error $("ERROR: " + $_.Exception.GetType().FullName); 
  write-error $("ERROR: " + $_.Exception.Message); 
 
  continue;   
 }

 $s = new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url);
 $startTime = [System.DateTime]::Now.Subtract([System.TimeSpan]::FromMinutes($minutes));
 
 $db_id = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase].getmethod("get_Id");
 $result_id = $db_id.Invoke($s.ContentDatabase, "instance,public", $null, $null, $null);
 
 $db_CurrentChangeToken = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase].getmethod("get_CurrentChangeToken");
 $result_CurrentChangeToken = $db_CurrentChangeToken.Invoke($s.ContentDatabase, "instance,public", $null, $null, $null);
 
 $startToken = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeToken([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeCollection+CollectionScope]::ContentDB, $result_id.ToString(), $startTime);
 
 $changeQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeQuery($False, $False);
 $changeQuery.Rename = $True;
 $changeQuery.Site = $True;
 $changeQuery.Web = $True;
 $changeQuery.Update = $True;
 
 $changeQuery.ChangeTokenStart = $startToken;
 $changeQuery.ChangeTokenEnd = $result_CurrentChangeToken;
 
 $db_GetChanges = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase].getmethod("GetChanges", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeQuery]);
 $result_GetChanges = $db_GetChanges.Invoke($s.ContentDatabase, "instance,public", $null, $changeQuery, $null);

 write-Output $result_GetChanges | Where-Object { $_.ChangeType -eq $changetype };

 $s.Dispose();
}
```

and to call using:

```
Get-ChangeLog -url http://your_site_url -minutes 120 -changetype Add
```

code above was taken from:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloshm/archive/2009/06/05/how-to-programmatically-read-the-changelog-in-powershell.aspx

the api involved is not in c# but atleast you know what to use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447550.aspx

the reason code above is slightly different is due to this:

> **Changes**
>
> Changes consist of a list of change events that need to be
> specially handled by the client.
>
> These are taken from our internal change log when a change token is
> supplied. For a full synchronization (no change token) we still return
> the Changes tag with the current change token.
>
> The limit on the number of updates returned from a change token is
> 100. The MoreChanges attribute indicates that the last change token is not current. More changes were done on the list and the client should
> call this method again with the new change token.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2008/01/21/synchronizing-with-windows-sharepoint-services-part-1.aspx

Comment: This also returnes all updated sites and webs, as well as the ones that are renamed. The rename property doesn't include a change of the title on a site or web, so there is no reason to include that. The update property includes the change of a title, but also includes a lot of other stuff, which I'm not interested in. I'm just wondering if there is a way to see if a praticular update IS a title change, or something else. I want to find what kind of update it was! Thanks for an answer, but it doesn't help, I think!

Comment: I use eh same code to get all the changes on my site collection , know how can i do toget the liste name ,web name , site name not only the id