# App Parts and Custom Actions in SharePoint apps at tenant scope

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, app, app-part

I have installed a sharepoint app at tenant scope. [Source 1](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/04/rolling-out-sharepoint-2013-apps-to.html), [Source 2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76473/find-if-a-site-has-been-renamed-via-change-collection).

In my app I have an app part, which is available in App Catalog (where the original app is installed). However on all other sites, *the app part is not available*, even though the app is there as a FullPage (immersive) app in Site Contents.

My question is why it is so, and my second question is:

**Could it be possible to provision app parts to all sites from an app installed at tenant scope?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179896.aspx)

> **Limitations of tenant-scoped apps**
>
> *The following kinds of apps cannot be batch-installed:*
>
> - Apps that contain a custom action for the ribbon. (Custom actions that are deployed as menu items are allowed.)
> - Apps that contain an app part.